# Is there any way to return a value in a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this:

```
var api = {
    getProduct : function(callback){
          //code anything
          //resp data 
          if(typeof callback == "function") callback(resp);
     }
}
```

There is anyway use like

```
var data = api.getProduct(function(resp){
  return resp;
});
console.log(data);
```

I need do something outside callback

Comment: what is the problem? Above code should works!

Comment: `return callback(...)` ?

Comment: @Grundy isn't `return callback(...)` a bit smelly?

Comment: @crl, why i think this? :-)

Comment: @crl :-D this a typo, it should be: _why **you** think this?_ :-)

Comment: because a callback is most often something asynchronous

Comment: @OP you are mixing synchronous and async data, it should be `api.getProduct(function(resp){console.log('deal with resp here')})` or the same with Promises